# xy tolerance from c#.net

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, .net

For some graph work, I need the value of [X,y tolerance](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/geodatabases/feature_class_basics.htm#dw_xytolerance). I found [ISpatialReferenceTolerance.XYTolerance Property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/XYTolerance_Property/002m000003r1000000/). But I couldn't find any option that how can I get `ISpatialReferenceTolerance` interface from the map? Can anybody give me some pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    double GetXyTolerance()
    {
        var map = ArcMap.Document.FocusMap;
        var spatialRef = map.SpatialReference;
        if (spatialRef!=null && spatialRef.HasXYPrecision())
        {
            var spRefTolerance = spatialRef as ISpatialReferenceTolerance;
            if (spRefTolerance != null && spRefTolerance.XYToleranceValid == esriSRToleranceEnum.esriSRToleranceOK)
                return spRefTolerance.XYTolerance;
        }
        return -1.0;
    }
```